# Ordering list of Pokemon

Tags: search, selection

I'm working on a companion site to help players with Pokemon Go, and one of the main components is a drop down that allows players to select a Pokemon from a list.

Traditionally in the Pokemon series, Pokemon are listed by index from 1-150. However, since this is aimed at users of Pokemon Go who may not be familiar with this tradition, I wasn't sure if such ordering would be appropriate.

In addition, I'm using the jquery select2 plugin which includes filtering as a user types in a textbox, to assist in location entries by name.

So with this context, would it be a better user experience to order by index as is typical of the Pokemon series and leverage filtering to locate entries by name, or should I simply order by name as is typical of most drop downs on the internet? Are there pros and cons to either pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Index would make sense as most users may begin to get familiar with that order as usage of the app increases. The select2 plugin offers a nice way for the user to zero in on a particular Pokemon they are looking for without needing to scan the entire list. I would say use index for consistency with the app. If you could style the list similar to how it appears in the app, that would also be a subtle clue to the user to make the connection back to the list found in the app.

Answer (score 0):

**Allow the user multiple methods for ordering.**

The [Binding of Isaac Cheat Sheet](http://platinumgod.co.uk/) does an excellent job at this, allowing the user to sort by alphabetical, color, item id, or the item's name in the search box.

By default, I would order the Pokemon by their index number, just like in the games. This is the standard ordering method for them, so seasoned players will recognize it almost instantly, and for new players likely this is the only ordering they've been exposed to.